# How to remove horizontal line table bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Is there any other way to remove the horizontal line of the table but the header should not? I'm using the `table-sm`, but it seems I cannot include it.

```css
.table-no-bottom-border,
.table-no-bottom-border td {
  border-top: 0px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: 0px solid white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html lang="en-US" web-base-url="http://localhost:1369">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
  <title>Report</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/web/content/302-9ddfff2/web.report_assets_common.css" data-asset-xmlid="web.report_assets_common" data-asset-version="9ddfff2">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/content/197-6f5d250/web.assets_common.js" data-asset-xmlid="web.assets_common" data-asset-version="6f5d250"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/content/303-9ddfff2/web.report_assets_common.js" data-asset-xmlid="web.report_assets_common" data-asset-version="9ddfff2"></script>




</head>

<body class="container">
  <div id="wrapwrap">
    <main>
      <div class="article o_report_layout_standard o_company_1_layout" data-oe-model="account.move" data-oe-id="2" data-oe-lang="en_US">
        <div class="page">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 75%; padding-right: 20%;">
              <table class="table table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="2"><span>CUSTOMER</span></th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-left"><span>SHIP TO:</span></th>
                    <th class="text-left"><span>BILL TO:</span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                  <tr class="font-weight-bold o_line_section">
                    <td class="text-left"><span>Collision Center</span> <span>
    <address class="mb-0" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        
        
            
    <div>
        
            <span itemprop="name">Collision Center</span>



            </div>


            <div itemprop="address" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">

                <span class="w-100 o_force_ltr d-block" itemprop="streetAddress">Sw 47 Terrace<br>Miami FL<br>United States</span>
              </div>






            </div>


            </address>
            </span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-left"><span>Collision Center</span> <span>
    <address class="mb-0" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        
        
            
    <div>
        
            <span itemprop="name">Collision Center</span>



          </div>


          <div itemprop="address" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">

              <span class="w-100 o_force_ltr d-block" itemprop="streetAddress">Sw 47 Terrace<br>Miami FL<br>United States</span>
            </div>






          </div>


          </address>
          </span>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <table class="table table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
              <tr style="height: 10px">
                <th class="text-center" colspan="2">
                  <span>TAX INVOICE #</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="font-weight-bold o_line_section text-center">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <h3 style="color: red;"><strong><span>/</span></strong></h3>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <table style="width: 100%" class="table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left"><span>CUSTOMER ORDER NO</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>CUSTOMER CODE</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>DELIVERY DATE</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>INVOICE DATE</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>SHIPMENT NUMBER</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>PACKED BY</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>NO. OF PACKAGES</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
            <tr class="font-weight-bold o_line_section">
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
              <td class="text-left"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <table style="width: 100%;" class="table-sm table-bordered table-no-bottom-border" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left"><span>LINE NO.</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>PART NO.</span></th>
              <th class="text-center"><span>DESCRIPTION</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>QUANTITY ORDERED</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>QUANTITY SUPPLIED</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>B.O.</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>PRICE</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>DISCOUNT</span></th>
              <th class="text-left"><span>TOTAL AMOUNT</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="invoice_tbody">



            <tr class="font-weight-bold">
              <td class="text-left"><span>1</span></td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_code">
                <span>101006</span>
              </td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_name"><span>[101006] G80 Master Link Large 6mm Type SD</span></td>


              <td name="qty_delivered" class="text-right"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="qty_ordered" class="text-right"><span>1.00</span></td>



              <td name="qty_bo" class="text-left"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="unit_price" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">5.73</span>
              </td>
              <td name="unit_discount" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">0.00</span>
              </td>
              <td name="sub_total" class="text-right o_price_total">
                <span class="text-nowrap">$&nbsp;<span class="oe_currency_value">5.73</span></span>

              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="font-weight-bold">
              <td class="text-left"><span>2</span></td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_code">
                <span>101010</span>
              </td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_name"><span>[101010] G80 Master Link Large Type SD 10/8mm</span></td>


              <td name="qty_delivered" class="text-right"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="qty_ordered" class="text-right"><span>1.00</span></td>



              <td name="qty_bo" class="text-left"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="unit_price" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">13.27</span>
              </td>
              <td name="unit_discount" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">0.00</span>
              </td>
              <td name="sub_total" class="text-right o_price_total">
                <span class="text-nowrap">$&nbsp;<span class="oe_currency_value">13.27</span></span>

              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="font-weight-bold">
              <td class="text-left"><span>3</span></td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_code">
                <span>101208</span>
              </td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_name"><span>[101208] G80 Multi Link Type MD 7/8mm</span></td>


              <td name="qty_delivered" class="text-right"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="qty_ordered" class="text-right"><span>1.00</span></td>



              <td name="qty_bo" class="text-left"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="unit_price" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">39.71</span>
              </td>
              <td name="unit_discount" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">0.00</span>
              </td>
              <td name="sub_total" class="text-right o_price_total">
                <span class="text-nowrap">$&nbsp;<span class="oe_currency_value">39.71</span></span>

              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="font-weight-bold">
              <td class="text-left"><span>4</span></td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_code">
                <span>101806</span>
              </td>
              <td name="account_invoice_line_name"><span>[101806] G80 Chain Connector Type CL | 6mm to 32mm\r\n(6mm)</span></td>


              <td name="qty_delivered" class="text-right"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="qty_ordered" class="text-right"><span>1.00</span></td>



              <td name="qty_bo" class="text-left"><span>0</span></td>
              <td name="unit_price" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">6.60</span>
              </td>
              <td name="unit_discount" class="text-right d-none d-md-table-cell">
                <span class="text-nowrap">0.00</span>
              </td>
              <td name="sub_total" class="text-right o_price_total">
                <span class="text-nowrap">$&nbsp;<span class="oe_currency_value">6.60</span></span>

              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>  

  </div>







  </main>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Also, is it possible to have a fixed height of a `<td></td>` even the `<tbody></tbody>` doesn't have record inside it?

```
 <div class="row">
    <table style="width: 100%" class="table-sm o_main_table table-bordered" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left"><span>CUSTOMER ORDER NO</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>CUSTOMER CODE</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>DELIVERY DATE</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>INVOICE DATE</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>SHIPMENT NUMBER</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>PACKED BY</span></th>
          <th class="text-left"><span>NO. OF PACKAGES</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
        <tr class="font-weight-bold o_line_section">
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
          <td class="text-left"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain which horizontal line exactly you mean? How I read it at the moment you want to have only a line between the header and the body and not other horizontal lines. Is this correct?

Comment: @Codeaur yes you are correct.